# Android SQLite Database: trouble creating table and inserting

Tags: android, sqlite

I am unsure what is going on with my simple program to learn how to use a SQLite database.  I based my program off the one found on [this site](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/06/simple-example-using-androids-sqlite_02.html).  I decided to remove the issue of using variables and just wrote everything into my Create table string.  I've also tried to do it with the appropriate KEY_CONTENT, etc to no avail. Hopefully this is enough code for you to see what is wrong.  Also, is there any code I could write (Log or Toast output) in that would help to figure out what's wrong?

```
public class SQLiteAdapter  {

public static final String DB_NAME = "My_Database";
public static final String DB_TABLE = "My_Table";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
public static final String KEY_CONTENT = "My_Content";


String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE = "CREATE TABLE My_Table (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, My_Content TEXT);";

private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

private Context context;

public SQLiteAdapter(Context c){
    context = c;
}
public SQLiteAdapter openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
      sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
      sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
      return this; 
     }
public SQLiteAdapter openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
      sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
      sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
      return this; 
     }

public void close(){
      sqLiteHelper.close();
     }

public long insert(String content){

      ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
      contentValues.put("My_Content", content);
      return sqLiteDatabase.insert("My_Table", null, contentValues);
     }
public int deleteAll(){
      return sqLiteDatabase.delete(DB_TABLE, null, null);
     }

     public String queueAll(){
      String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_CONTENT};
      Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(DB_TABLE, columns, 
        null, null, null, null, null);
      String result = "";

      int index_CONTENT = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTENT);
      for(cursor.moveToFirst(); !(cursor.isAfterLast()); cursor.moveToNext()){
       result = result + cursor.getString(index_CONTENT) + "\n";
      }

      return result;
     }

     public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

      public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
        CursorFactory factory, int version) {
       super(context, name, factory, version);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

       db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);
      }

      @Override
      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }

     }
```

}

My main activity starts dealing with the SQLite DB like this:

```
mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
        mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
        mySQLiteAdapter.insert("First try");
```

And here is the Logcat:

```
04-25 14:19:37.404: E/Database(217): Error inserting My_Content=First try
04-25 14:19:37.404: E/Database(217): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: My_Table: , while compiling: INSERT INTO My_Table(My_Content) VALUES(?);
04-25 14:19:37.404: E/Database(217):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.native_compile(Native Method)
04-25 14:19:37.404: E/Database(217):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compile(SQLiteProgram.java:110)
04-25 14:19:37.404: E/Database(217):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
04-25 14:19:37.404: E/Database(217):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
04-25 14:19:37.404: E/Database(217):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1027)
04-25 14:19:37.404: E/Database(217):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1413)
04-25 14:19:37.404: E/Database(217):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1286)
04-25 14:19:37.404: E/Database(217):    at com.willmer.trialsqlite.SQLiteAdapter.insert(SQLiteAdapter.java:53)
04-25 14:19:37.404: E/Database(217):    at com.willmer.trialsqlite.TrialSQLiteActivity.onCreate(TrialSQLiteActivity.java:25)
04-25 14:19:37.404: E/Database(217):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-25 14:19:37.404: E/Database(217):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
04-25 14:19:37.404: E/Database(217):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
04-25 14:19:37.404: E/Database(217):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
04-25 14:19:37.404: E/Database(217):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
04-25 14:19:37.404: E/Database(217):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-25 14:19:37.404: E/Database(217):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-25 14:19:37.404: E/Database(217):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-25 14:19:37.404: E/Database(217):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 14:19:37.404: E/Database(217):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-25 14:19:37.404: E/Database(217):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-25 14:19:37.404: E/Database(217):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-25 14:19:37.404: E/Database(217):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I suggest you don't call any database tables 'Table' - it's a reserved word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your Code with the Following code.
Because `Table` itself is a Keyword.

```
String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE = "CREATE TABLE My_Table (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, My_Content TEXT);";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give space between "Table" , "("  and "Values" , "(".

like below

```
INSERT INTO Table (Content) VALUES (?);
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  How do I add the spaces when I'm using sqLiteDatabase.insert("Table", null, contentValues);
even if I change all the Table's and Content's to My_Table and My_Content.